# Run action filter even if action is cached

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, caching

I have an action filter which is registered as global

```
GlobalFilters.Filters.Add( new SaveAdSourceFilter() );
```

The filter just saves some Referer information into Cookies to use it later.
Now i enable caching mechanics via OutputCache attribute and the filter stops being called.

Is there a way to bypass caching for my filter?
I know some other solutions like implementing IHttpModule but ActionFilter is a bit simplier.

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom implementation of OutputCache, e.g. Donut Output Caching.

You can read more here: [Working with the Output Cache and other Action Filters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10990337/working-with-the-output-cache-and-other-action-filters)