# ASP.net MVC Logging Page Views

Tags: asp.net-mvc, logging

Is there an easy way to log every page hit by any user.
I am thinking this will sit within the global.asax.cs file, so that I can write to a db table the URL of the page being hit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found a way to complete this problem which seems to fit my purpose.

I use the PostAuthenticateRequestHandler method, as it is called for every page hit.
I ignore any empty path and just "/" as these are not actual pages hit.

```
//in global.asax.cs file

private void PostAuthenticateRequestHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   ///...///

   string extension = this.Context.Request.CurrentExecutionFilePathExtension;
   string path = this.Context.Request.CurrentExecutionFilePath;

   if (extension == string.Empty && path != "/")
   {
   PageVisitedLogModel pageVisitedLogModel = new PageVisitedLogModel
   {
       DateVisited = DateTime.Now,
       IPAddress = this.Context.Request.UserHostAddress,
       PageURL = this.Context.Request.RawUrl,
       Username = this.Context.User.Identity.Name
   };

   //then writes to log
   DataHelper.UpdatePageVisitedLog(pageVisitedLogModel);
}
}
```

Comment: I know this is 3 years old, but I have a question... what if your site is being hit by bots?  Will this log those as hits as well?

Comment: Yes it will log all hits, including those by bots.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be to use a global action filter, as in [this example](http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/archive/2010/08/15/asp-net-mvc-3-global-action-filters.aspx). This allows you to run some code for any action in your solution.

Comment: What happens if the action output is cached? will the action filter will work at that time?

Comment: No, if you use the standard output caching this would not fire, but there is a solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10990337/working-with-the-output-cache-and-other-action-filters