# MVC 4 - How to apply a filter before OutputCache

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, caching

I want to apply a filter before the OutputCache is applied.

I have this controller annotation

```
[OutputCache(Duration=3600,VaryByCustom="TypeOfDevice", Order=10)]
public ActionResult Index()
```

I defined the `GetVaryByCustom` method in `Global.asax` .

Also, I apply a filter of type `ActionFilterAttribute` in `Global.asax`

```
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        // Register track filter
        GlobalFilters.Filters.Add(new FrontEnd.Filters.MyFilter(), 0);
```

The first time  `MyFilter` is executed, but the following request do not reach the filter and the response comes from the `OutputCache`.

How could I apply the `MyFilter` before the `OutputCache`.

Thanks in advance

**Update:**

`MyFilter` is an `ActionFilterAttribute` with the method override

```
 public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
 {
    // SET A COOKIE

    base.OnActionExecuting(context);
 }
```

Comment: You might find a hint and/or an explanation in this thread, [SO-10990337](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10990337/working-with-the-output-cache-and-other-action-filters). Let me know either way.

Comment: It would be helpful to see the definition of MyFilter. Are you overriding OnActionExecuting or OnResultExecuting or are you even deriving from ActionFilterAttribute?

Comment: @CrnaStena I would prefer to not use DonutOutputCache because it's not the standard way to do the caching. I prefer to stay with the official MVC way. I tried to override OnResultExecuting in MyFilter, maybe it would be called like with Donut as the link explain, but not.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could inherit from [OutputCacheAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.outputcacheattribute(v=vs.118).aspx) and override [OnResultExecuting](http://forums.asp.net/t/1703571.aspx?Extending%20OutputCache%20Attribute%20in%20asp%20net%20mvc%203)

Comment: It's a way to turnaround the problem, but you get tightly coupled with OutputCacheAtribute implementation.